# Revolutioner vs Revolutionist: which is better?

Tags: nouns, variants

Both words can be found in a dictionary and have the same meaning. My question is: is any one better than the other in any way? Is one more fitting in certain scenarios?

I think *revolutionist* sounds more natural but I'm not sure. I've been living in Eastern USA for about 5 years so could it be that *revolutionist* is just more common in my area?

Comment: Compare the suffixes *-er* and *-ist* -- there's significant difference, though they are both used in a general sense, sometimes even incorrectly.

Comment: In general, an *-er* is a practitioner, an *ist* is a believer in the philosophy. And there's *revolutionary* anyway. What meaning are you actually trying to convey? Can you include an example sentence, and maybe the broader context?

Comment: @Kris An example sentence would be "He was a great revolutionist."

Comment: That won't help at all. What kind of a person do you mean by "revolutionist?"

Comment: @Kris I don't have a specific person in mind but I mean someone that causes and is involved in a revolution (like the founding fathers of USA)

Comment: According to Wiktionary and also some dictionaries, *revolutioner* is **archaic**, so it may be avoided.

Comment: I frankly don't ever recall (in my 65 years) seeing or hearing "revolutioner".  I may have heard "revolutionist" a handful of times.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine what a "revolutionist" or "revolutioner" is, as opposed to a "revolutionary".  Maybe an ice skater or a dancer who is expert at revolving around in a circle rapidly.

Comment: I've never heard the world "revolutioneer" used in any context, nor does it make any sense, but I'd be willing to make it happen. ;)

Comment: "Revolutioner" does not appear in my copy of the Concise Oxford.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If what you are looking for is this sentence "he was a great revolutionist" then the correct way of saying it would be: he was a great [revolutionary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutionary); " Che Guevara was a great revolutionary."

Revolutionary: a person who either actively participates in, or advocates revolution. Also, when used as an adjective, the term revolutionary refers to something that has a major, sudden impact on society or on some aspect of human endeavor.

Comment: I see, I had only seen "revolutionary" being used as an adjective. Is there any occasion where "revolutionist" would be a better choice? or is it just preference?

Comment: In AmE I have only seen "revolutionary". I can imagine  "revolutionist" referring to one who advocated but did not participate in a revolution, but I cannot imagine using "revolutioner" in any context.

Comment: Why would *He was a great revolutionist* be incorrect? [noun 1. a person who advocates or takes part in a revolution.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revolutionist)

Answer (score 11):

We almost always use *revolutionary* (versus *revolutionist* or *revolutioner,* etc.) to name (noun) or describe (adjective) someone who caused, led, supported, or was important to a revolution (major and fundamental change).

From the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA):

> *And here's a young girl on a horse who was a **great revolutionary** heroine, so you should by all means stop and see that one.*

Date: 1994 (19940703); Title: Authors Remember American Women's Historical Landmarks; Source:   NPR_Weekend.
[Davies, Mark. 2008- The Corpus of Contemporary American English: 450 million words, 1990-present. Available online at https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/.](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)

> *The Christian ministry has been located on the corridor for 10 years. "King was such a **revolutionist,"** Thomas said. " That's what we're trying to do.*

Date: 2000 (20000113); Publication information: CityLife Atlanta (Extra); Title: A stroll down MLK Drive;The road named for the civil rights leader tells a story as it meanders through town; Author: S.A. Reid, Staff; Source: Atlanta Journal Constitution. 
(Same source.)

*Revolutionary* appeared 7,877 times in the COCA, while *revolutionist* appeared 12 and *revolutioner* 0.

Comment: If it's a cause we favored.

Comment: Your first example isn't actually to point: it's using *revolutionary* as an adjective, not a noun.

Answer (score 5):

According to The New Fowler's Modern English Usage-

> The form in **-ist** is first recorded as a noun in the sense 'one who
>   instigates or favours revolution' in 1710 and was the customary word
>   until the mid-i9c.
>
> Since then it has been **challenged by revolutionary**
>   (*the OED entry leads off with
>   a quotation of 1850 from Charles Kingsley's Alton Locke*).
>
> Both words are still current.  **The usual choice is [revolutionary](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/revolutionary).**

Modern US examples:

- Songs ... are a resource both for the loyalists defending their
  country and the revolutionists overthrowing it—Harper's Mag., 1991;
- Oratory and organization were the basic skills of the revolutionist
  and he had both—J. Pournelle and S. M. Stirling, 1993
- An obituary in The New York Times described her as “an incorrigible revolutionist to the end- NY Times, 2012

*Like the word revolve, it's all about turning things around.*

Answer (score 0):

Consider the context: did the revolution succeed or fail? In AmE you will see Che Guevara described as a revolutionary far more often than George Washington, who was a founding father, fighter for independence, creator of the nation - a successful revolutionARY.

One interpretation of revolutionIST would be "one who is a specialist in revolutions" which might denote a history professor doing comparative research (e.g. between English, French and American revolutions) or even a mercenary type consulting on how to promote revolution, both meanings carry the implication that the revolutionIST is not personally committed to the revolution i.e. s/he is NOT necessarily a revolutiuonARY.

One would expect RevolutionER to be equal to RevolutionARY, unless revolutioner happens to be a term used within the re-enactor community to distinguish between "revolutioners", "civilists", and soon.